# Can I call or run Core Data Main Context (viewContext) from a background thread?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm using only Core Data's Main Context in my application. I know that Main Context can be run only Main thread.
However, when I am updating the main context from inside a background thread, I don't face any crash.

```
    //Cloudkit operation
 let zoneOperation = CKFetchRecordZoneChangesOperation(recordZoneIDs: zonesIDs, optionsByRecordZoneID: [zonesIDs[0]: options])

 zoneOperation.recordChangedBlock = { (record) in

// This is background thread
 print("Record has changed")
    let date = record["date"] as! Date

//Fetching Managed Object Context from Coredata (Main Context)
if let migraine = migraine(OnDate: date, inContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext) {
migraine.date = date
saveData(inContext: self.persistentContainer.viewContext)
}
}
```

How I am able to execute Coredata Main Context save inside a background thread without crash?

Comment: Create a deadlock situation then you'll see it dying and believe me this will happen in your production code, when you've multiple requests to the core data. While testing you're just creating one thread and one request

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So does that mean I Can call or run Core Data Main Context (viewContext) from a background thread?

Comment: Could you at least indent your code

Comment: it’s all about inconsistency as long as there isn’t any, the main or bg thread doesn’t matter. a main thread is a thread but high priority. Naming it UI thread doesn’t change anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `perform(_:)` or `performAndWait(_:)` to ensure changes to a context happen on the thread that the context belongs to.

```
persistentContainer.viewContext.performAndWait { 
  self.saveData(inContext: persistentContainer.viewContext)
}
```

You can also do something similar with

```
persistentContainer.performBackgroundTask { context in
  // Do stuff on this context and arrange for the changes
  // to be merged back to the view context. 
}
```